# symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, lookup, symbols

I am writing a shared library with C++ under Ubuntu. The source code contains two files: ClassA.h and ClassA.cpp. Bellow are parts of the contents:

ClassA.h:

```
namespace calss_a{
class ClassA{
public:
   ...
   void foo(int nBlockIndex);
   ...
}
}
```

ClassA.h:

```
namespace calss_a{
    ...
   void classA::foo(int nBlockIndex){printf("....");}
    ...
}
```

The compiled .so file from the above source codes is used in test.cpp as follows:

```
...
class_a::ClassA * ptr = new class_a::ClassA();
...
ptr->foo(0);
...
```

However, when the executable build from test.cpp runs, there is an error as follows:

symbol lookup error: /home/hzhu/test: undefined symbol: _ZN16class_a15ClassA16fooEj

But if I change in ClassA.cpp and ClassA.h the type of foo()'s argument "nBlockIndex" from "int" to "unsigned in", and recompile the .so file, then the problem disappears. In a further experiment, the argument "nBlockIndex"'s type is still defined to be "int", but in test.cpp I call "foo" this way:

```
ptr->foo(1); //pass 1 instead of 0
```

then the problem disappear as well.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a spelling mistake in your first snippet: `calss_a` instead of `class_a`.

Comment: Can you post demangled form of "_ZN16class_a15ClassA16fooEj"? (My GNU c++filt is unable to demangle) Also can you check the undefined symbols in the executable? When I get this error I usually find the expected symbol (unmangled version) vs the supplied symbol. You can run nm on .so and the executable to get this info..

Comment: The same typo is in the second snippet too.

Comment: If the spelling consistency of your actual code is the same as consistency in your question, I think we have the answer. Not just the calss_a/class_a thing, but changes in case too.

Comment: After three hours, we don't have any clarifications.  You've put up four very brief samples of code that presumably are similar to what you actually wrote - but not from your code, because in that case all the names would be spelled and capitalized uniformly.  There isn't anywhere near enough information here to do anything.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit new to this kind of thing myself, but I am also running into a symbol lookup error and so thought I would share what I have found out.

The problem with symbol lookup errors usually is that something is being defined two different ways in two different places. If you do

```
 nm -u your-executable | grep undefined-symbol
```

then you will find out where the symbols being used in an object file or executable file are defined